# Tomcat 7 takes much time on startup

Tags: tomcat7, web.xml, catalina

In tomcat 6, it just takes 14 or 15 seconds to startup the build.

I've read about startup slowness on the net about Tomcat 7

Also i've followed the steps from this link - http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Configure_your_web_application

I've added the below attributes in <**web-app>** element in web.xml

**xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true"**

and an empty element

**abosolute-ordering**

If i exclude jar scanning using **catalina.properties** it just takes 10 or 11 seconds. But i don't want to use that property file as it changes default behaviour of Tomcat.

Currently it takes almost 1 minute when catalina.properties is not used. I've added the above **metadata-complete** attribute & an empty **absolute-ordering** Still it take this much time.

Please help me if there is any other good solution.

Comment: but if the default behaviour is not what you want, why not simply change it ?!? Talking of speeding up: you could add -Xverify:none to your JRE parameters (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#BABFEFGF) But I am not sure if removing all those functions that are there for good reasons makes sense